# How to transform a named JsArray into a JsObject with JsZipper

Tags: json, scala, playframework

Let's assume either of the following two JSON snippets:

```
{ "include": ["field1", "field2", "fieldN"] }
{ "exclude": ["field1", "field2", "fieldN"] }
```

I need to transform the `include` array like this...

```
{ "field1": 1, "field2": 1, "fieldN": 1 }
```

... and the `exclude` array like this:

```
{ "field1": 0, "field2": 0, "fieldN": 0 }
```

[Just for your info: I need to transform input JSON into Mongo's projections.]

Here below is my current solution – I've implemented it as a `JsValue` extension:

```
object testTypeExtensions {

  implicit class TestJsExtensions(val json: JsValue) extends AnyVal {

    def toProjection: JsValue = {
      if (json \\ "include" nonEmpty)
        JsObject(for (field <- (json \ "include").as[List[JsString]])
        yield (field.value, JsNumber(1)))
      else if (json \\ "exclude" nonEmpty)
        JsObject(for (field <- (json \ "exclude").as[List[JsString]])
        yield (field.value, JsNumber(0)))
      else Json.obj()
    }
  }
}
```

The code above works...

```
scala> val p = Json.obj("exclude" -> Json.arr("field1", "field2"))
p: play.api.libs.json.JsObject = {"exclude":["field1","field2"]}

scala> p.toProjection
res12: play.api.libs.json.JsObject = {"field1":0,"field2":0}
```

... but I'm sure it could be written much better with `JsZipper`.

Furthermore it is not very flexible since it only manages the `include` and `exclude` keys, whereas I want to also manage other similar cases like sorting objects:

```
{ "asc": ["field1", "field2"] }
{ "desc": ["field1", "field2"] }
```

... transformed into...

```
{ "field1": 1, "field2": 1 }
```

... and

```
{ "field1": -1, "field2": -1 }
```

That said, what I've in mind is a generic method that manages any kind of named JSON array like:

```
object testypeExtensions {

  implicit class TempJsExtensions(val json: JsValue) extends AnyVal {

    def namedArrayToObject(keys: String*): JsValue = {
      // how to implement it, possibly with JsZipper
    }

  }
}
```

The `namedArrayToObject` method should search for the specified `keys` in the current JSON and generate an object for the **first match** like the ones I described at the beginning of this post, possibly with `JsZipper`. Here is a simulation of the expected results.

Search for `exclude` and `include` and return the first match as a `JsObject`:

```
scala> val p = Json.obj("exclude" -> Json.arr("field1", "field2"))
scala> p.namedArrayToObject("exclude", "include")
res12: play.api.libs.json.JsObject = {"field1":0,"field2":0}
```

Same as before... but now input JSON contains `include` instead of `exclude`:

```
scala> val p = Json.obj("include" -> Json.arr("field1", "field2"))
scala> p.namedArrayToObject("exclude", "include")
res12: play.api.libs.json.JsObject = {"field1":1,"field2":1}
```

Search for `asc` and `desc` and return the first match as a `JsObject`:

```
scala> val p = Json.obj("desc" -> Json.arr("field1", "field2"))
scala> p.namedArrayToObject("asc", "desc")
res12: play.api.libs.json.JsObject = {"field1":-1,"field2":-1}
```

... and so on.

If there is no match, `namedArrayToObject` should return an empty `JsObject`. Any suggestion  on how to implement this in the right way would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Travis helped me to find the way... and here below eventually is my solution that does exactly what I was looking for:

```
object testExtensions {

  implicit class testJsExtensions(val json: JsValue) extends AnyVal {

    def toParams(pairs: (String, Int)*): JsValue = {
      for (pair <- pairs) { json.getOpt(__ \ pair._1).map { values =>
        JsObject(for (field <- values.as[List[JsString]])
        yield (field.value, JsNumber(pair._2)))
      } match {
        case Some(params) => return params
        case _ =>
      }}
      Json.obj()
    }
  }
}

scala> example.toParams(("include", 1), ("exclude", 0))
res63: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"field1":1,"field2":1,"field3":1}

scala> example.toParams(("exclude", 0))
res64: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"field4":0,"field5":0,"field6":0}
```

Again a bit thanks to Travis :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this pretty straightforwardly with [JSON transformations](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.3/ScalaJsonTransformers):

```
import play.api.libs.json._

def toObj(value: Int) = Reads.of[List[String]].map(
  keys => Json.toJson(keys.map(_ -> value).toMap)
)

val transformation =
  (__ \ 'include).json.update(toObj(1)) andThen
  (__ \ 'exclude).json.update(toObj(0))
```

We can define an example object and apply our transformation:

```
val example = Json.parse("""{
  "include": ["field1", "field2", "field3"],
  "exclude": ["field4", "field5", "field6"]
}""")

val transformed = example.transform(transformation)
```

And then:

```
scala> transformed.foreach(Json.prettyPrint _ andThen println)
{
  "include" : {
    "field1" : 1,
    "field2" : 1,
    "field3" : 1
  },
  "exclude" : {
    "field4" : 0,
    "field5" : 0,
    "field6" : 0
  }
}
```

This doesn't exactly match your desired API, but it should be easily adaptable, and I'd suggest staying away from the implicit class business, anyway—it's much less composable and makes handling invalid input less elegant.

Comment: Tx for your great explanation. The problem is that input JSON cannot contain both "include" and "exclude"; if so, only the first match should be taken. For example, having your "example" JSON as an input, "toObject" should just return {"field1" : 1, "field2" : 1, "field3" : 3}. That's why I was considering JsZipper...

Comment: You could get something close to that behavior by combining `orElse`, `andThen`, and `prune`, but JSON objects are unordered, so "_first_ match" doesn't (or at least shouldn't) mean anything.